# How to Connect Multiple Devices to AWS IoT Using Shared Certificates?

Tags: c++, amazon-s3, esp32, arduino-ide, aws-iot

I have to connect multiple IoT devices and to connect them to AWS IoT using shared certificates.I am using Nodemcu esp32 ad the the device.currently I have configured to run for single thing.I also created a S3 bucket also created Iam role that grants the registration task access to AWS IoT and S3 as the first step to connect many things but as for the next step

> **An error occurred while submitting the bulk registration task. InvalidRequestException: Cannot assume provided role
> Provide Feedback on your experience - optional**
> can someone provide guidelines to create many things

I have try to create Iam role and grand multiple permissions for it and retry to create many things but there is an error **Cannot assume provided role**